# Flutter: The instance member '_buildFormTextFields' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: forms, flutter

I am trying to make a form (temporarily) using the code below, but before I can even run the code I get hit by the error message: "The instance member '_buildFormTextFields' can't be accessed in an initializer". The code of '_buildFormTextFields' is accessible and nothing seems wrong with it, how do I fix this issue?

```
Widget textFormFields = Container(
    child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildFormTextFields("Sport"),
        _buildFormTextFields("Aantal deelnemers"),
        _buildFormTextFields("Locatie"),
        _buildFormTextFields("Begintijd"),
        _buildFormTextFields("Eindtijd"),
        _buildFormTextFields("Speelniveau"),
      ],
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing the body to return the column, this cleared the error message, my solution is shown below:

```
  Widget textFormFields() {
    return Container(
        child: Column (mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget> [
            _buildFormTextFields("Sport"),
            _buildFormTextFields("Aantal deelnemers"),
            _buildFormTextFields("Locatie"),
            _buildFormTextFields("Begintijd"),
            _buildFormTextFields("Eindtijd"),
            _buildFormTextFields("Speelniveau"),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either make it `static` (which means it does not use instance level data and can safely called at any time) or if that is not possible, then you have to move your initialization into the constructor or a method that is called after the constructor is done (for example `initState`).